# Log out of Apple TV

Tags: appletv

Can you sign out of Apple TV using an iPad or phone? I logged into my exs Apple TV and now I am not sure what he can see or use in my stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Go to https://appleid.apple.com/ log in with your AppleID and password. In the next page, scroll down and you will see every device you have signed into with that AppleID. You can remove any device from the list right from within that interface by clicking on the device you wish to remove and confirming the removal.

Comment: This method worked for me to "log out" of my Apple TV+ account on an ex's FireTV. That is, it allowed me to remove their device as an authorized device allowed to use my Apple ID.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is probably to change your Apple ID password. However, you would then have to sign in to all your own devices again using the new password.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not, you could use the Remote app but you would have to be on the same network as the AppleTV and be able to see its output. Which probably isnt an option as its your ex's.  I would go with Scott's answer, as inconvenient as it might be, it will prevent unauthorized access to your account.